# Gerar APK com certificado privado usando o Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Quando clico em "Run" no eclipse ele gera o APK, envia e instala no Android, mas ele instala usando um certificado Debug, estou usando o Google Games Services e ele somente funciona caso o APK esteja com um certificado privado (aquele que criamos para enviar para o Google Play), e não funciona com certificado Debug...

Sei que tem como exportar um o projeto já incluindo o certificado privado direto do eclipse, e sei que da para instalar este APK que contem o certificado via adb

ex:

```
./adb -d install -r /diretorio/arquivo.apk
```

A minha dúvida é, se é possível mudar este botão de run, para que quando clicado execute a mesma função, mas utilize o certificado privado em vez do Debug.
Tem como?

Pesquisei, vi uma resposta no SO gringo, mas não consegui entender, então creio que há um meio.

Comment: Põe aqui o link da resposta que viste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu utilizo o [Android ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), mas acredito que seja o mesmo local se você estiver utilizando o Eclipse com o plugin ADT separadamente.

Acesse o menu **ADT** (ou **Eclipse**) e então abra as **Preferências**. Na opção **Android > Build**, você pode definir uma nova *keystore* nos campos *custom*, como mostra na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tento mas aparece um erro... "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect", mas não tem um lugar para por password, e estou selecionando a mesma keystore que uso no meu app via adb

Comment: @felipe.rce Não existe um lugar para informar a senha realmente, o ideal é você alterar para senha padrão que é **android** enquanto desenvolve ou gerar outra *keystore* com a senha padrão.

Comment: não tem como alterar a senha que já uso? Ou tenho que criar outro keystore? Enquanto procurava por esta resposta vi a um tempo um cara do SO gringo falando que depois de alterações como essas, o Google leva um tempo para começar a sincronizar com seu APP... Até horas (me parece que ele estava enganado, não é possível!), então estou com receio de criar outro keystore e modificar no Google Play, pois quero publicar daqui a pouco tempo... É meu primeiro app (é um game)...

Comment: [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2889605/1216394) tem uma forma de alterar a senha.